# How to display a particular user's email only in the to section in the mail after sending mail to multiple users using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail, nodemailer

When I send an email to multiple user using nodemailer as given below.
In the body, `to` is coming as `'one@gmail.com, two@gmail.com'`

```
const mailOptions = {
  from: 'from@gmail.com',
  to: request.body.to,
  subject: request.body.subject,
  text: request.body.text,
}
let result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions)
```

Now when I open the mail and see

```
from: from@gmail.com
to:   one@gmail.com
      two@gmail.com
Date: 20 July 2021
```

in the 'to' section: all user's email is shown. Though I've sent mail to multiple users, I want to display the email of that particular user only(who the email is receiving) in the to section. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

#### To get the effect you want, send the email multiple times, once to each person

That way the "to" of each person's email will reflect only them.

An alternative would be to send it to yourself, and just BCC all recipients, but I think you don't want that because it seems impersonal.

#### You don't have to wait for each email to send, before starting the process of sending the next

In your current code which is slow, you are probably `await`ing the result of `sendMail` for each recipient, *before* starting the next `sendMail`.

```
const recipients = ["a@gmail.com","b@gmail.com"];

const promiseArray = recipients.map(recipient=>{
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'from@gmail.com',
        to: recipient,
        subject: request.body.subject,
        text: request.body.text,
    }
    return transport.sendMail(mailOptions)
})

const resultArray = await Promise.all(promiseArray)
```

However by taking the approach here, you will initiate all the individual `sendMail`s first, and then wait for all the individual promises to resolve. This should scale much better.

Comment: But what if the number of recipients grow. We have to send it multiple times. I tried sending using loop but it takes a lot of time. I tried sending an email to 3 users using a loop, the response time in postman was more than 10 sec.